# Vue Component Props Derived

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue (2) component --

```
Vue.component('item-component', {
    props: ['item'],
    template: `<div :id="???">item.name</div>`
})
```

with HTML --

```
<template v-for="item in items">
  <item-component v-bind:item="item"></item-component>
</template>
```

items are --

```
items = [{ itemid: 1, name: "Foo" }]
```

The question is: how can I generate *derived* id value like --

```
<div id="my-item-1">Foo</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use:

```
<div :id="'my-item-'+item.itemid">Foo</div>
```